# Maven failing to run Junit Tests on mvn -test

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, selenium, junit

I have some Selenium Webdriver tests that I'd like to run from command line using mvn -test. Problem is that I can clean, build and compile with no issues but no tests run.  I get no message relating to test such as "There are no tests to run."

My junit tests are following the *test class naming convention.

I have compared my POM with another project that runs tests no problem and it is identical, bar the project name and location. The project which works is under my User directory but the one that doesn't is directly underneath c:\

I'm not proficient enough to be able to debug this with mn -x yet so any help much appreciated. Here is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>websiteRegression</groupId>
<artifactId>websiteRegression</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<name>websiteRegression</name>
<url></url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Full access to hamcrest matchers

    see https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest
    you can add hamcrest-core for the foundation matchers
    and you can add hamcrest-library for more extensive libraries
    or you can add hamcrest-all for everything if you don't want to think about it
   -->
    <!-- Junit 4.11 needs hamcrest 1.3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- if we use junit-dep then we can bring in the full hamcrest -->
    <!-- JUnit 4.10 depends on hamcrest 1.1 -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- Use JUnit as our test framework -->
    <!-- this gives us basic hamcrest -->
    <!-- <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.10</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency> -->


    <!-- if I want to use a version of hamcrest above 1.1 with 4.10 then I need an exclusion -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    -->


    <dependency>
        <!-- bring in the full selenium deploy
             we could be more selective and bring
             only what we need -->
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.39.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
        <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<!-- I have added the build section to support importing into
     IntelliJ automatically without throwing errors about wrong Java
     Version. This basically says the source requires at least Java 1.7
     and use a compiler that outputs Java 1.7 -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>anyBrowserTests</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/AllBrowserSuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>firefoxTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/AllBrowserSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaAndIESuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FireFoxOnlySuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnIEOnlySuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>ieTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/AllBrowserSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>chromeTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/AllBrowserSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnIEOnlySuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>operaTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/AllBrowserSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnIEOnlySuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>failingOperaTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaAndIESuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>failingIETests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaAndIESuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnIEOnlySuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>failingChromeTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaAndIESuiteTest.class</include>
                            <include>**/FailOnChromeAndOperaSuiteTest.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
    <reporting>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.16</version>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

EDIT:  Ok, I found it was a problem with Profiles - fixed!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, I found it was a problem with Profiles - fixed!